# Ошибка в классе.NameError:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начинающий программист, учусь работать с классами.

```
class Dog():
    my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
    print("My dog's name is " + my_dog.name.title() + ".")
    print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

Ошибка:

```
File "klas.py", line 1, in <module>
    my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
NameError: name 'Dog' is not defined
```

Comment: А где у вас описание класса Dog? Оно должно идти в коде до того, как вы его используете

Comment: Ну нет, так не пойдёт, класса самого у вас так и нет, есть только заголовок от него, после чего вы сразу инстанциируете экземпляр класса и пытаетесь им пользоваться. Как минимум в классе вам надо инициализатор `__init__` описать, принимающий два параметра и размещающий их значения в полях класса `name` и `age`.

Comment: все спасибо я поняла уже и сама все исправила

Answer (score 3):

```py
class Dog:
    
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "My dog's name is %s.\nMy dog is %s years old." % (self.name, self.age)


dog = Dog('Bobik', 5)
print(dog)
# My dog's name is Bobik.
# My dog is 5 years old.
```

Comment: форматирование через процентную нотацию уже не в моде. Лучше интерполяция через `f`-строки

Comment: @cauf. Я не модный.))) И к тому-же с PyMySQL привык, там такая нотация очень даже в ходу до сих пор, а если через `f'{}'` то приходится костыли для форматирования значения под БД выдумывать

Comment: А что на счет метода `str.format()`?

Comment: @cauf, такая же хрень. в `cursor.execute()` есть 2 параметра (основных) это форматированная строка запроса и список значений под этот формат, вот тогда и  `None` в `NULL` нормально переводится и строковые значения кавычками в нужных местах обрастают, а по другому приходится костыли писать

Comment: Да, "тяжела и никозиста ...". Сочувствую!

Comment: А зачем тут аннотации `str` и `int`?

Comment: @dIm0n ну как бы указание ожидаемых типов данных. В нормальных IDE при написании кода при попытке впихнуть туда другой тип данных подсвечивает как предупреждение, лично мне очень помогает когда код не 2 строчки.

Comment: @Namerek вот теперь это имеет смысл, а до этого они ссылались на значения, которые уже говорили о типах, поэтому писать там же аннотацию типа показалось мне странным

Comment: @dIm0n, ну да, чето тупанул. Они там вообще не нужны были.